# Is it possible to reference entire row in check constraint?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.4, database-trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_validate_func(obj JSON)
RETURNS BOOLEAN AS $$
  return true;
$$ LANGUAGE plv8;

CREATE TABLE tbl (col1 TEXT, col2 INTEGER)
CHECK (my_validate_func(row_to_json(*))); -- syntax error :(
```

I would like to invoke my own validation function for entire row using `CHECK` constraint instead of trigger - is it possible?

Comment: what error do you get?..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (
  col1 TEXT,
  col2 INTEGER,
  CHECK ( my_validate_func(row_to_json(tbl.*)))
);
```

would not give you DDL error :)

Answer (score 2):

`row_to_json(tbl.*)`, or simply `row_to_json(tbl)`, should do the trick.